# Rhythmbox missing from sound applet on tray after reinstall on uhuntu 12.04 gnome classic

Tags: 12.04, gnome, sound, indicator, rhythmbox

I had an rhythmbox in sound applet on tray but i had a problem in rhythmbox recently, when i wanted to play something rhythmbox was just playing some weird noise so i reinstalled rhythmbox

And after reinstall of rhythmbox, it disappeared from sound applet.

And now i have only sound indicator, rhythmbox is disappeared.

How do i get rhythmbox back to be like this?

http://ubuntuguide.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/rhythmbox.png

Now it's only mute and sound settings.

I would show you better but my reputation doesn't allow me to post images sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you reinstall rhythmbox plugins?

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

After that start rhythmbox and check your preferences under Edit->Plugins, and make sure that

- **Media Server2 D-Bus Interface**
- **MPRIS D-Bus Interface**

are checked. Then a reboot/logout may be necessary.

Comment: MPRIS D-Bus interface plugin was inactive, i didn't know for what it is so i didn't touched that. Now it's working nice. Thanks alot.